# How can python run multiprocessing spawn without __main__

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, spawn

I extend my c program with some piece of python code(initial a python env in c, then import a function from python module and run it), In which situation I had to call multiprocessing module and spawn a process without __main__ function, I know that it worked in __main__, but can I do something in my C program and make it possible to execute multiprocessing spawn outside of __main__.

*file x.c*

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *module_name = PyUnicode_FromString("t1");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\"./\")");
    cout << "Python Version: " << endl << Py_GetVersion() << endl << endl;
    PyObject *module = PyImport_Import(module_name);
    PyObject *func = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "run");
    PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("()");
    PyObject_CallObject(func, args);
    Py_DECREF(args);
    Py_DECREF(func);
    Py_DECREF(module);
    Py_DECREF(module_name);
    return 0;
}
```

- Makefile *

```
all:
    g++ -O0 -g3 -std=c++11 x.c $(shell python3-config --includes) $(shell python3-config --ldflags) -o a.out -Wall
```

*file t1.py*

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing as mp


def test():
    print("hello world")



def run():
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    # ctx = mp.get_context('fork')
    p = ctx.Process(target=test, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()

# run()
```

call run function from x.c will print nothing, while add run() at the end of t1.py and run directly with python3 t1.py it will raise 'freeze_support' error.

*t2.py*

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing as mp


def test():
    print("hello world")



def run():
    # ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    ctx = mp.get_context('fork')
    p = ctx.Process(target=test, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

This script can print a hello world if called run function from x.c

*t3.py*

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing as mp


def test():
    print("hello world")



def run():
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    # ctx = mp.get_context('fork')
    p = ctx.Process(target=test, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

This script run seperately(python3.5 t3.py)works as well(print hello world at the end)

I want to execute run function without a __main__ entry in a c program(through PyObject_CallObject), Then, how could I make it work.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is please also provide the relevant C code (+ compilation steps). Please also include the full error message.

Comment: Hi @a_guest I have already updated my question, provided with c, makefile and three python script.

Comment: What is your version of Python and the OS you're running the code on?

Comment: Hi @a_guest, this is a common problem on python3.x. I tested on Centos7.6 with python3.5.6.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of section [Contexts and Start Methods](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) is the following warning:

> **Warning:** The `'spawn'` and `'forkserver'` start methods cannot currently be used with "frozen" executables (i.e., binaries produced by packages like **PyInstaller** and **cx_Freeze**) on Unix. The `'fork'` start method does work.

Since `multiprocessing` creates the new process from within the current one, which runs a compiled (i.e. frozen) executable, it is not possible to use `'spawn'` as the start method.

You can continue to use '`fork`' however (as you described this works for your example).